# Does lim$_{a \rightarrow b } \space d(a,b) = 0 $ imply completeness in a metric space?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Suppose $<M,d>$ is a metric space.

Does lim$_{a \rightarrow b } \space d(a,b) = 0 $ imply completeness in a metric space?

Or maybe lim$_{a \rightarrow b } \space d(a,b) \neq 0 $ implies incompleteness in a metric space?

It seems to have been correct with 3 examples I've tried it on.

But intuitively, it doesn't seem satisfactory to me.

It seems to show the sequence is Cauchy but I can't understand why this might imply convergence. (A friend said it did).

Any ideas?

Suppose we have the incomplete metric space$ (M, d) $ s.t.

$M=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 :||x|| < 1  \} $

$d(x, y)= 2 - ||x||-||y|| $ if $x \neq y$,  and $0$ otherwise

The original question I asked is only true here when $||b||=1$ which can't be the case given the definition of the space $M$

Comment: No, this just says that $d$ is continuous in the topology of $d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow b}d(a,b)=0$$
is true of all metric spaces. Just expand what it means:

> For all $\varepsilon$, there is some $\delta$ such that if $d(a,b)<\delta$ then $d(a,b)<\varepsilon$.

Which is trivially satisfied by putting $\delta=\varepsilon$. So, in particular, it tells you nothing about completeness. In words, the statement says (more or less):

> All sequences converging to $b$ get arbitrarily close to $b$.

which is very different from the notion of completeness, since completeness starts with a Cauchy sequence and says it converges, whereas here we've started with a sequence we already knew converged and said it converged.

Comment: Oh good to know, I was confused by OP.

Comment: So to make the story short, the question makes no sense right? It is equivalent to asking: is every metric space complete?

Comment: @dREaM The question is mathematically well formed; it asks if the statement $\lim_{a\rightarrow b}d(a,b)=0$ is in any way related to completeness. The answer is that it does not, because that statement is always true.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: See my edit.  I'm confused, it seems to contradict what you said. What am I missing?

Comment: @GregoryPeck I suspect you're taking the limit with regard to the Euclidean metric (i.e. saying $a$ gets close to $b$ in the Euclidean metric) whereas this is not the limit associated with the space $(M,d)$ that you give. In particular, since for any point $x$ in your space one has that the ball $B(x,1-\|x\|)=\{x\}$, all sequences converging to $x$ are, after a point, just repeating $x$'s, so any sequence of $a$ going to $b$ is eventually just $b$'s so $d(a,b)$ is eventually just $0$.

Comment: Of course,  that makes sense.  Thanks